# wordpress mu subdirectory site not loading

Tags: mamp, wordpress

I have copied a live wp multisite install ( grabbed everything via ftp ) and installed it on my mac ( I am using MAMP PRO ).

I found that the main site works like a charm. the second site doesn't work at all. If you try to hit it, it ends up throwing a 404 and redirects to the homepage.

I have checked the .htaccess and the wp-config.php and they are correct. I haven't changed the domain ( using the same domain on my mac as on live )

The interesting bit is that I can reach the wp-admin of the subdirectory site.

```
http://domain.com - working
http://domain.com/subdirectoryinstall - not working
http://domain.com/subdirectoryinstall/wp-admin - working
```

Anyone has this happen before?

Oh if it makes any difference it was wordpress 3.0.1 ( yeah I know what you think ) and now upgraded to 3.9.1

Comment: Try to refresh the Permalink structure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I thought I had done this already but I did it again to make sure and it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm not on my machine to check my configs, but explain how you configured this *"I haven't changed the domain ( using the same domain on my mac as on live )"*

Comment: I'm using MAMP Pro and used it to create my virtual hosts for me. So even though I go to www.domain.com I am actually loading my local copy.

I am doing this so I don't have to change any urls as this can be a pain with MU installs

Comment: oh, I never did that. I suppose you have to shut down MAMP to see the real thing...

Comment: I installed the rewrite rule inspector plugin and it seems like it is looking for a page called the same as the subdirectory.

Comment: ok I came to the realisation that it is simply a compatibility issue when you go from 3.0.1 to 3.9.1